# Junction Object between same SObject Type (b-directional siblings)

Tags: junction-object

What is the best way to implement a Junction object that connects two of the same SObject Types?

I have a data-structure that sort of represents a sibling relationship.  Each `Treatment__c` has 0 or more related Treatments.

Example:

Given Treatment A, B, C & D

- A is related to B & C
- B is related to A & C & D
- C is related to A & B
- D is related to B

Seems like you would probably need to implement this with a standard junction object (`Related_Treatment__c`):

`Treatment_1__c`
`Treatment_2__c`

but this creates challenges around how you properly query and ensure data  integrity.

For example, given Treatment A, you don't know if you should look for all records where Treatment A is in `Treatment_1__c` or `Treatment__2__c`.

The alternative would be to essentially have two records for each relationship (`A-B` & `B-A`).  The problem with this is you now have to ensure that they stay in sync (IE if you delete one you must delete the other).

You you just have to check both?  or is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best options is to create a trigger that runs after insert update and clones each junction except reverses the lookups.

This provides the following benefits but costs data storage,etc:

- related lists look as they should on related records, since lookup 1 can always be should and will appear
- queries are consistent as you mentioned
- other ui contexts like reports are more consistent/faster since you can always just filter on one of the two columns

One thing that makes the approach much easier is to always upsert on a composite key of the lookups. This will make your code simpler, prevent duplicates, and remove the need to requery the table (performance).

For after delete you can also put a self referencing lookup. Then, in the after delete context you always also delete this record (so the recipricol pairs are deleted together).

Comment: also worth noting, this trigger is going to need to run after delete and update (assuming reparenting is allowed; it probably shouldn't be)